# Using Fetch to make a post request to google forms returns a pre-flight cors error

Tags: reactjs, post, cors, fetch

I am using google forms to make a POST request from the frontend of my app. The app has a custom form and I am using google forms to keep track of the responses. I am trying to make a POST request but I keep getting a CORS error when ever the request has been made. I have tried multiple different content-types to no avail. Was hoping someone would be able to help me out here.

Error being recieved:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScXpwaAVEzgbI7SJfLDAxduZP-3dJRvraiYgxEspA2Kof8-gA/formResponse' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Code

```js
        const google_url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScXpwaAVEzgbI7SJfLDAxduZP-3dJRvraiYgxEspA2Kof8-gA/formResponse"        
        const request = new Request(google_url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'GOOGLE-FORM ID': handleNameChange, 
                'GOOGLE-FORM ID': handleEmailChange,
                'GOOGLE-FORM ID': handleMessageChange,
            })
        });
        
        fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })   
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err)
            })
```

Comment: *I keep getting a CORS error* [...] What does the error message say? That piece of information should be in your question.

Comment: Updated question with error received, sorry its pretty late for me so i totally forgot to put it in

Comment: try to run your application as secure like, add  "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start" and run. This will end up in a not secured connection. then just used proceed anyway or type "THISISUNSAFE", you will be able to access. You are not getting a secured connection due to there being no SSL certificates added for local.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your shell:

```sh
curl -s -D - \
  -o /dev/null -XOPTIONS \
  -H 'Origin: http:localhost:3000' \
  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
  'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScXpwaAVEzgbI7SJfLDAxduZP-3dJRvraiYgxEspA2Kof8-gA/formResponse'
```

The output doesn't contain the required CORS response headers for the preflight access-control check to succeed, which indicates that the endpoint in question is not CORS-aware.

Short of using some (secure!) CORS proxy, there isn't much you can do on your end.